# How to convert lists to a dataframe using a reference dataframe as a map?

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have this dataframe which has three columns that I am trying to use as a map to link three different lists into a (source-target) 2 columned dataframe.

Here is the 3-columned mapping dataframe that I am using as reference:

```
COLOR   PATTERN     DAY
red     chequered   monday
blue    dots        monday
-       cross       monday
magenta leaves      thursday
yellow  -           friday
-       custom      saturday
red     leaves      friday
-       chequered   wednesday
blue    cross       sunday
green   -           sunday
red     cross       tuesday
yellow  dots        -
yellow  stripes     -
magenta custom      -
```

**Example input**

```
color=['blue', 'red', 'yellow']
patter=['stripes', 'custom']
weekday=['sunday', 'tuesday', 'monday', 'friday']
```

**Desired output**

```
blue    monday
blue    sunday
red     monday
red     tuesday
red     friday
yellow  stripes
yellow  friday
```

How should I go about it?

Comment: Are your list items variables or strings?

Comment: The list items are strings, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
color=['blue', 'red', 'yellow']
patter=['stripes', 'custom']
weekday=['sunday', 'tuesday', 'monday', 'friday']

# boolean indexing
new = df[(df['COLOR'].isin(color) & df['DAY'].isin(weekday)) | (df['COLOR'].isin(color) & df['PATTERN'].isin(patter))]

# new conditions
cond = [
    new['DAY'] != '-',
]
# your choice list
choice = [
    [new['COLOR'].values.tolist(), new['DAY'].values.tolist()]
]

# numpy.select to create list
data = np.select(cond, choice, [new['COLOR'].values.tolist(), new['PATTERN'].values.tolist()])

# create new dataframe and transpose
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data).T

        0        1
0     red   monday
1    blue   monday
2  yellow   friday
3     red   friday
4    blue   sunday
5     red  tuesday
6  yellow  stripes
```